# Multidimensional dictionary in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have a python script that parses an XML file that contains part information as well as a command on what the script should do with the information.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<servicexml>
    <action>
        <command>Add</command>
        <partnumber>1223</partnumber>
        <partname>Battery</partname>
        <partdescription>Holds charge</partdescription>
    </action>

    <action>
        <command>Add</command>
        <partnumber>4444</partnumber>
        <partname>Pump</partname>
        <partdescription>Pumps stuff</partdescription>
    </action>

</servicexml>
```

I am attempting to write a python script that will strip out all relevant information and put it into a dictionary so I can look up values by key. Currently my code can only hold a single dimension - this means that in my XML file the last   tag is the only value written. How Can I dynamically allocate dimensions in my dictionary to hold multiple actions from my XML file? This way I can access key values for each part sequence.

Here is my Python code

```
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO

actionInformation = []
tagsOfInterest = ['command','partnumber','partname','partdescrip']
tagDataOfIntrest = {}
xmlFile = "parts.xml"
context = etree.iterparse(xmlFile)

for action, elem in context:
    if elem.tag in tagsOfInterest:
        actionInformation.append([elem.tag,elem.text])

tagDataOfInterest = dict(actionInformation)    
print tagDataOfInterest
```

## **SOLUTION Based on David Alber's Answer**

I had to change some of the imported modules however his method was still used.

```
from lxml import etree
xmlFile = "parts.xml"
context = etree.parse(xmlFile)
actions = context.findall('action')

parsed = [{field.tag: field.text for field in action} for action in actions]
```

Comment: You could create a list of dictionaries, where each list element corresponds to one of the `action`s. For instance, you would have `[{'command': 'Add', 'partnumber': 1223, 'partname': 'Battery', 'partdescription': 'Holds charge'}, {'command': 'Add', 'partnumber': 4444, 'partname': 'Pump', 'partdescription': 'Pumps stuff'}]`. Does something like that sound all right to you?

Comment: That is basically what I was trying to accomplish. This way I could easily access any of the individual action keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach that works. It does not make the `partnumber` elements integers, but it does not look like you were doing that anyway. It would not be much trouble to modify it for that, though.

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse(xmlFile)
actions = tree.findall('action')

parsed = [{field.tag: field.text for field in action} for action in actions]
```

## Fully self-contained example

Here is a fully contained example to allow easy verification. The difference is that `xmlFile` from above has been replaced with a `StringIO` object.

```
import StringIO
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

s = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<servicexml>
    <action>
        <command>Add</command>
        <partnumber>1223</partnumber>
        <partname>Battery</partname>
        <partdescription>Holds charge</partdescription>
    </action>

    <action>
        <command>Add</command>
        <partnumber>4444</partnumber>
        <partname>Pump</partname>
        <partdescription>Pumps stuff</partdescription>
    </action>

</servicexml>"""

st = StringIO.StringIO(s)

tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse(st)
actions = tree.findall('action')

parsed = [{field.tag: field.text for field in action} for action in actions]
```

After running this, you can do

```
>>> parsed
[{'command': 'Add',
  'partdescription': 'Holds charge',
  'partname': 'Battery',
  'partnumber': '1223'},
 {'command': 'Add',
  'partdescription': 'Pumps stuff',
  'partname': 'Pump',
  'partnumber': '4444'}]
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? For some reason it can't find etree.ElementTree

Comment: @user1130161 I have Python 2.7. The [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) component is new in Python 2.5 and appears to have had various changes in Python 2.7.

Comment: I got rid of the errors by changing the import to: `from lxml import etree` and then `xmlFile = "parts.xml"
context = etree.parse(xmlFile)
actions = context.findall('action')
parsed = [{field.tag: field.text for field in action} for action in actions]`